# VIIRS Snow Cover Data Product in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, raster-conversion

I'd like to incorporate the VIIRS Snow Cover Data Product (global
version VNP10C1) into my GEE code because of it's increased 375m-resolution compared to the MODIS Snow Cover Product (500-m resolution).

The only workflow I can find is to upload the VIIRS Snow Cover Data Product into ArcGIS for my dates of interest (2018-2020) and area of interest (Scandinavia), convert to raster (Band CGF_NDSI_Snow_Cover), then upload to GEE as multiple .tiffs.

Is that the best method for dealing with data for multiple years and an aoi of that size? Is there a way I can link to the data (https://nsidc.org/data/VNP10A1F/versions/1) from GEE and pull directly to GEE so I can visualize it there?

Answer (score 1):

In general, data must be uploaded to Earth Engine before it can be processed in Earth Engine. So, you must either upload the part you want to use yourself, or you can request that it be added to the Earth Engine Data Catalog.

[The procedure for making a request is documented here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help#dataset_requests) and in this particular case, [there is already an outstanding request for VIIRS VNP10A1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143730060). As suggested, you can star the request and perhaps add a comment describing how it would be useful.

Of course, that will take some time even if the request is prioritized, and proceeding with uploading the data you need yourself is likely the best option in the short term to make some progress. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the data format or ArcGIS, so I cannot advise you as to whether there is a better workflow for the conversion.